# Running mysql query on php multiple times but with different condition

Tags: php, mysql

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX29j.png

im currently making an invoice receipt. the numbers you see on the image, 4600 and 33, are the retrieved values from the checklist from the first page. As you can see, it only lists ONE charge where as it should be two.

this is the part of the code:

```
$procedures = $_SESSION['receipt'];

        foreach($procedures as $key=>$procedureno)
            {
            $query = "select * from `charges` where `procedure_no` = $procedureno";
            echo $procedureno;
            $result2=mysql_query($query,$dbh1);
            if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0 ){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
            echo '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row[1].'</td>
                <td>'.$row[2].'</td>';

            echo '</tr>';
                }
    }

            }
```

I want this query $query = "select * from `charges` where `procedure_no` = $procedureno"; to be executed several times depending on how many the $procedureno is.

Comment: You are about to get a lecture on mysql injection...

Answer (score 2):

MySQL understands lists. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM charges WHERE procedure_no IN (1, 5, 33, 78)
```

Comment: $procedureno=4600 33. How can I replace the space with comma?

Comment: Do you even know what you are doing? Try `str_replace($procedureno, ' ', ',')`. Definitely not the best way, but here's not the place to teach you PHP basics...

Comment: It should be str_replace(" " , ", ", "$procedureno"); but either way it doesnt work

Comment: Just take my query and send it to the database manually. You will see that it actually does work. It's the most straightforward solution to your problem.

Comment: Yeah it works in sql. But my problem is doing it on a php code since there is no comma in the variable.

Comment: It would be a lot easier and faster, if you tried thinking on your own for a bit. Apparently all of the relevant procedure numbers is in `$procedures` in your script. So what you need to put into the `IN (...)` should be `join(', ', array_values($procedures))`. And then you don't need most of your sourcecode anymore, because you only need to loop over the result and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method and pass the condition as a parameter. 
Inside that method put your FOR cycle.